# Twitter authentification Failed to validate oauth signature and token

Tags: zend-framework, twitter, frameworks

I created twitter authentication on my website and everything worked fine, but after some time I started receiving error message "Failed to validate oauth signature and token". I have changed my consumerKey and consumerSecret, but it didnt help. I use zend framework. Here is my first step:

```
public function authtwitterAction()
{
$zendConfig = Zend_Registry::get( 'Zend_Config' );
// Instance oauth consumer with config options
$consumer = new Zend_Oauth_Consumer($zendConfig->twitter->toArray());                     
// Using the default session namespace, we store the request token serialized
$session = new Zend_Session_Namespace();
$session->requestToken = serialize( $consumer->getRequestToken() );
// Redirect user to twitter.com
$consumer->redirect(); 
}
```

I send my consumerKey  and consumerSecret to http://twitter.com/oauth and it's my callbackUrl: http://onlinefitnesclub.ru/twitter. Probably something changed in twitter?

Comment: search the site. there's millions of twitterers with the same error message. e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652284/failed-to-validate-oauth-signature-and-token

Answer (score 3):

I have solved my issue. I send my request to http://twitter.com/oauth, but when I changed protocol to **https**://twitter.com/oauth everything work fine again.